# Do database access generators return new rows that are added while using them?

Tags: python, mysql

More specifically, if I iterate through a database using a python db api which emulates a generator giving me one row at a time, will the generator also return new rows that I create in the meantime?

My guess would be yes as I think the implementation of such a generator would involve a cursor that simply goes to the next row whenever a new row is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the generator also return new rows that I create in the meantime?

If you mean: "rows created by an other connection while I was iterating", the answer is "No".

---

Simply speaking, when to perform your SELECT query, you are seeing a "snapshot" of the DB. Concurrent changes to the DB are not visible from that snapshot.

As a matter of fact, if you use transactional tables (i.e.: InnoDB), and depending your [transaction isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html), changes made by other connections might not be visible until you open a new transaction (remember that in [auto_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) mode, a new transaction is open for you at each request).

Answer (score 1):

No.

Once you have made a sql query, and start retrieving results, you can't be sure new rows will be int he results set.

The results could be in memory, or in buffer on the db.

You could to do something like;

```
while ( result = "SELECT .... where processed=0 LIMIT 1" )
{
   do processing
   Run Sql "UPDATE row set processed=1 where id = result[id]"
}
```